# Automorphisms of rational normal curves are elements of $PGL(n+1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Note**: By automorphism the following is meant: A regular function from the rational normal curve $C\to C$ as well as an inverse regular function.

I have received as a hint that all automorphisms from $\mathbb P^1$ are linear (i.e. elements of $PGL(n+1)$). Through this, one can calculate explicitly that any automorphism of a rational normal curve is linear which, in the end, is true due to the fact that $GL(V)$ acts linearly on $Sym^n(V)$ for every $n$.

I was wondering if anyone could help me unravel what this hint means and how I can calculate the linearity of the automorphism. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since a rational normal curve is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^1$, you already know the automorphisms of the curve are just $PGL(2)$. If that's not what you're asking, you ought to clarify your post.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right and the hint is superfluous. Thank you very much!